# Typo3 list the content of all child-pages as content of the parent page

Tags: menu, parent-child, typo3, typoscript

As the title says, I need to list the content of all child-pages on the parent-page, after its own content. Or the thing I really need is, one page with content and and a menu which links to the different headers of the content. e.g. athe parent-page with content:

```
**Parent Head**
parent text
*first subhead*
first subtext
*second subhead*
second subtext
```

and the menu should look like:

Parent

-first subhead

-second subhead

I thought it would be easier if the parent-page "collects" the content of the child-pages.
The other solution was, that the child-pages would be links to extern URLs, to the specific *c*-IDs of the different contents of the parent-page. But I think this isn't that easy for the website owner, who doesn't know anything about where he can find the right *c*-ID in the web-page-source-code.
So how would You make that? Or how can I realize the thing with the child-page-content?

**EDIT: Have a solution now. Just have to fix, that the submenu will be displayed without childpages.
Here is the code:**

```
temp.contentnav = CONTENT
temp.contentnav {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 7
    orderBy = sorting
    where = colPos=0
    languageField=sys_language_uid

  }
  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = header
    wrap= <li>|</li>

    typolink.parameter.field=pid
    typolink.parameter.dataWrap=|#{field:uid}
    typolink.ATagParams = class="linkClass"
    if.isTrue.field=header
  }

  wrap = <ul id="submenuClass"> | </ul>
}

page.10.marks.MENU.2.NO.after.cObject < temp.contentnav
```

Comment: Try to use typoscript queries.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
temp.pageIds = HMENU 
temp.pageIds.entryLevel = 1 
temp.pageIds.1 = TMENU 
temp.pageIds.1 { 
  NO.stdWrap.field = uid 
  NO.allWrap = |, 
  NO.doNotLinkIt = 1 
} 
lib.container = CONTENT 
lib.container.table = tt_content 
lib.container.select { 
  pidInList.cObject < temp.pageIds 
}
```

Comment: I found that too and it works, but how can I link the submenu items to their content on the parentpage?

Answer (score 0):

There is a content element "Menu/Sitemap" with has an option to render subpages with content.

If you want to do it via TypoScript, render the menu, and then replace the menu items with content of them.

```
  # Pseudocode on menuitem
  # assuming you are using css_styled_content
  1.allStdWrap.cObject < styles.content.get
  # Set pid for CONTENT object from styles.content.get to the uid of the page
  # which gets rendered
  1.allStdWrap.cObject.select.pidInList.data = uid
```

Can't provide you with an working snippets atm.